# Search questions by views not working

Tags: bug, search, filtering, search-box

On the [How do I search?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) page it is said that I can use the range operator to search questions by views:

> `views:500..1000` or `views:500-1000` will return posts with 500 to 1000 views

However, when I try the filter [`views:1..10`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=views%3A1..10) the first results will have 973, 90, 30, 55 views.

And when I try the filter [`views:1-10`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=views%3A1-10) the first results will have 55, 585, 973, 90 views.

I tried to filter by `score` and `answer` and the range operator works fine there.

So why is it not working on views and why is there a different result when I use `..` and `-` ?